# os.listdir analog for a zipped directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, zip

My goal is to list all files contained in the certain **sub**-directory inside a zip-archive.

`os.listdir(target_dir)` raises a `FileNotFoundError`, and `zfile.namelist()` just lists all the files in all directories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
files = list(filter(lambda f: f.startswith("subdir"), zfile.namelist()))

print(files)
```

Explanation: `filter` filters the list supplied by `zfile.namelist()` on a `lambda` that is checking whether the filename starts with "subdir".

The `filter` function does not return a list but rather a filter object (generator) and thus we need to convert it to a list.

You could also use the following line which does the same but uses list comprehension:

```
files = [f for f in zfile.namelist() if f.startswith("subdir")]
```

Edit: As pointed out by [advance512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925011/os-listdir-analog-for-a-zipped-directory/37925346?noredirect=1#comment63301600_37925346): "The problem with this solution is that it will also return files in subdirectories inside the subdirectory you're checking.":

```
files = [f for f in zfile.namelist() if f.startswith("subdir") and f.count("/") == 1]
```

This will not return any files in sub-sub directories.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will also return files in subdirectories inside the subdirectory you're checking. If this is what you're looking for, then it's a good solution (I generally prefer lambdas and comprehensions too, but you were asking for a function).

Comment: @advance512 Thank you, I did not consider that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a regex expression to get all files (≠ sub-directories) of the specific sub-directory: `files = [f for f in zipfile.namelist() if re.compile("^(" + re.escape("subdir") + r"\/[^\/]*?)$").match(f)]`. But in this case you have to import and use the `re` module. Because of that I prefer more @SimonKirsten original answer.

Comment: Also, in @Darius code example, you'd compile the regexp once per each file name... bad performance. If anything, compile the regexp outside of the comprehension. Regexps do seem a bit overkill in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the supplied `zip_listdir` function, which is a bit quick-n-dirty but should always work in Unix clones.

```
class MockZipFile(object):
    fake_file_names = [
        "string.pyc",  # Top level name
        "test/__init__.pyc",  # Package directory
        "test/test_support.pyc",  # Module test.test_support
        "test/bogus/__init__.pyc",  # Subpackage directory
        "test/bogus/myfile.pyc"  # Submodule test.bogus.myfile
    ]

    def namelist(self):
        return self.fake_file_names


def zip_listdir(zip_file, target_dir):

    file_names = zip_file.namelist()

    if not target_dir.endswith("/"):
        target_dir += "/"

    if target_dir == "/":
        target_dir = ""

    result = [ file_name
               for file_name in file_names
               if file_name.startswith(target_dir) and
                  not "/" in file_name[len(target_dir):]
               ]

    return result

mockZipfile = MockZipFile()
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="test")
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="test/bogus")
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="test/")
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="/")
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="")
print zip_listdir(zip_file=mockZipfile, target_dir="/asd")
```

Please note I created a MockZipFile class, and am using it as the input for the `zip_listdir` function, but a proper [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) object should work exactly the same.